# How do blue light filtering lenses work? Is it possible that they could they negatively impact your vision?

Tags: optometry

I have had some recent trouble with my vision and while trying to figure out what was going on one of the possible factors was a blue light reflective coating on my lenses.  While that has been mostly ruled out at this point I am still curious about how likely this is to be an issue at all.

So, how does this blue light coating work?  Is it possible that this filtering could have an impact on your vision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways (proprietary methods) that these blue light coating are manufactured, but one general principle is called anti-reflection coatings. *I say "one general method" because hybrid methods can exist depending on the manufacturing company.

Anti-reflection coating:

The coating creates two reflections (on each side of the coating) that destructively interfere (cancel each other out), thus reducing the amount of blue (high energy) light reaching the eyes. This is the reason why the coating is promoted to help alleviate eye strain from computer light.

[image: Hyperphysics]

---

Physics behind the image: 
Index refraction of coating is somewhere between air (~1) and glass (~1.5); the coating's thickness is around 1/4*light's wavelength (number varies, but should be around blue/green area of light spectrum).

---

From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be any negative impact on vision/eye health by reducing the amount of blue light that reaches your eye.

These blue light coatings remind me of the 'orange sunglasses/blue blocking glasses' and research is still being done to study how reducing blue light yields health benefits such as eye protection, improving cortisol level and better sleep.

---

References:

[Different types of blue light coating](https://www.readingglassesetc.com/pages/blue-block/blublock-ar-coatings.html)

[Physics behind Anti-Reflection Coatings](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/antiref.html)

[Neat Information on Blue Light, the Good and the Bad](http://www.allaboutvision.com/cvs/blue-light.htm)

[Research on benefits of blocking out blue light](https://wellnessmama.com/15730/blue-light-blocking-glasses/)